# Add Sales per Day

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have a query that essentially should bring the total sales per day but I don't know what I'm doing wrong in the query that brings me all the sales without adding the days.

```
$ventasdia = DB::select('SELECT DATE_FORMAT(v.fecha_venta,"%d/%m/%Y") as dia, sum(v.monto) as totaldia from ventas v where v.id_estado_venta="2" group by v.fecha_venta order by
        day(v.fecha_venta) desc limit 12');
```

This is what the query brings me:

[image]

As can be seen, the days are repeated and it does not add up per day.

Comment: If you want to sum this data per day, why not use `GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(v.fecha_venta,"%d/%m/%Y")`? What does `fecha_venta` contain?

Comment: the query does use group by, I use the date format because the "fecha_venta" field has the date of the sale but in datetime format

Comment: datetime format means that you group by the day **and time** - that will obviously not sum up sales per day, but sum up all sales that share the same day **and time**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `GROUP BY dia` not by `v.fecha_venta`.
If you group by v.fetch_venta it groups by the datetime and this is probably different for every row.

Comment: thanks for the help and the correction grouping it by the day if it works for me, thanks.